# Match a pattern in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

There is an array with 2 elements

```
test = ["i am a boy", "i am a girl"]
```

I want to test if a string is found inside the array elements, say:

```
test.include("boy")  ==> true
test.include("frog") ==> false
```

Can i do it like that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Using Regex.

```
test = ["i am a boy" , "i am a girl"]

test.find { |e| /boy/ =~ e }   #=> "i am a boy"
test.find { |e| /frog/ =~ e }  #=> nil
```

Comment: @izomorphius True, but the poster did not specify if the string had to be a separate word or not. Simple to fix with a different Regex.

Comment: in fact I had some troubles creating the other regex. How do you say end of string or \w?

Answer (score 46):

Well you can grep (regex) like this:

```
test.grep /boy/
```

or even better

```
test.grep(/boy/).any?
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to reverse it, i.e. to pass `match` to `any?`, so it wouldn't have to check all strings.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can do

```
test = ["i am a boy" , "i am a girl"]
msg = 'boy'
test.select{|x| x.match(msg) }.length > 0
=> true
msg = 'frog'
test.select{|x| x.match(msg) }.length > 0
=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

I took Peters snippet and modified it a bit to match on the string instead of the array value

```
ary = ["Home:Products:Glass", "Home:Products:Crystal"]
string = "Home:Products:Glass:Glasswear:Drinking Glasses"
```

USE:

```
ary.partial_include? string
```

The first item in the array will return true, it does not need to match the entire string.

```
class Array
  def partial_include? search
    self.each do |e|
      return true if search.include?(e.to_s)
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Curiously enough, I needed this too in ruby core class Array.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to monkeypatch the the Array class you could do it like this

```
test = ["i am a boy" , "i am a girl"]

class Array
  def partial_include? search
    self.each do |e|
      return true if e[search]
    end
    return false
  end
end

p test.include?("boy") #==>false
p test.include?("frog") #==>false

p test.partial_include?("boy") #==>true
p test.partial_include?("frog") #==>false
```

Comment: I would not necessarily say that this is the "best" way per se considering that class modifications are available in every other ruby code / project too. It definitely is one way though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if a word included into the array elements, you can use method like this:

```
def included? array, word
  array.inject([]) { |sum, e| sum + e.split }.include? word
end
```